# ms teams : response action

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

We are trying to automate in MS teams that will :

- Parse json
- HTTP Post to API
- Get HTTP Response
- post comment to the chat using adaptive card.

We created a BOT using power automate, and we created a flow  using :

- for selected message
- parse JSON
- HTTP Post to API
- Post comment to the chat. using adaptive card

But when we add "response" in power automate using below flow :

- for selected message
- parse JSON
- HTTP Post to API
- Response
- Parse JSON body (parse body from Response).
- Post comment to the chat. using adaptive card

Upon saving, we are getting this error :

```
Flow save failed with code 'WorkflowUnsupportedSplitOnTriggerForResponseAction' and message 'The workflow with 'Response' action type should not have triggers with 'splitOn' property defined: 'manual'.'.
```

Please advise the correct flow to rectify above issue ?

Comment: Looks like you have attached some triggers (with 'splitOn') with action type  as "Response", Could you try removing it and try it.
Also could you please share any docs URL which you are referring.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft - i am following this docs URL - https://d365demystified.com/2020/07/29/accept-http-requests-in-a-flow-and-send-response-back-power-automate/.  so..without "Response", how can we validate the response body returned by HTTP POST ?

Comment: This is by design. You can only add the response flow step after the request action.
The response for the trigger is available as properties. Please refer to this thread for a similar issue.
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/unable-to-use-a-response-action/td-p/378804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from comment's section :

This is by design. You can only add the response flow step after the request action. The response for the trigger is available as properties. Please refer to this thread for a similar issue.
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/unable-to-use-a-response-action/td-p/378804